# JQuery 3.1.1 and CSS flexbox

Tags: jquery, css, flexbox

When using JQuery's fade functions, if an element starts with 'display: none' and then is faded out, JQuery will inject 'display: block' when the item is faded in.

In a flexbox layout, this results in the element wrapping to the next line.

When I disable `display:flex` on the parent it behaves as expected.

Is there a way to disable `display:flex` on specific elements that need to be hidden initially?

I can overcome this by just using:

```
$('el').fadeIn().css('display','inline-block');
```

But this method isn't desirable in this case. Any suggestions?

Here is a demo

```js
$('#clickme').click(function() {
  $('#test').fadeToggle();
  return false;
});
```

```css
#flex {
  display: flex; /* BREAKS JQUERY FADE, JQUERY INJECTS DISPLAY:BLOCK; */
  flex-direction: column;
}
#main {
  flex: 1;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<body id="flex">
  <div id="main">
    <span class="tools"> 
      <a class="a" href="" id="clickme">Click Me</a>
      <span id="test" class="hidden">I should be inline!</span>
    </span>
  </div>
</body>
```

If you disable `display:flex` on `#flex` it works as expected/desired.

Comment: A demo here might be useful

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/60xush0w/

Comment: I don't think this is possible natively using Jquery's *"fade"*. There is no "display:flex-item" which is what **should** be applied. Unfortunately, you may have to write your own function here.

Comment: Yea, this seems like the way to go -- thanks!

Comment: Ah...no, I think I have it...you need to apply flexbox to the tools span - https://jsfiddle.net/60xush0w/2/ Answered as such.

Comment: @Paulie_D But his `<span>` element with `id` test is not a flex-item, I'm still wondering why it adds `display: block;` instead of inline.  Applying flex to his tools span will now make `#test` a flex-item, that's why your solution works.

Comment: Works for the example, but it wraps the entire span, which should remain inline

Comment: Yes, I know but there is no display:flex-item` but it sort of negates the `display:block` by making the parent a flex-container.

Comment: Yep, but just curious where jquery is getting 'display:block' if it's going by 'initial' which should be 'display:inline' on a span?

Comment: I do not recommend using `display: flex;` in your `<body>` tag. This may be one of the many issues you could encounter and there is no need to use flexbox for a two dimension layout.

Comment: I only put the bare minimum to illustrate the issue in the demo .. I'm trying to keep a footer always on the bottom of the viewport without using absolute positioning ..

Comment: Another hack'ish solution is to not initially set display:none and use jquery to .hide() the elements on load.

Answer (score 1):

That's because, when you show an element, jQuery must make a guess about its `display`. That's because CSS was poorly designed. `dislay: none` should have never existed.

jQuery does this in its `getDefaultDisplay` function:

```
function getDefaultDisplay( elem ) {
    var temp,
        doc = elem.ownerDocument,
        nodeName = elem.nodeName,
        display = defaultDisplayMap[ nodeName ];

    if ( display ) {
        return display;
    }

    temp = doc.body.appendChild( doc.createElement( nodeName ) );
    display = jQuery.css( temp, "display" );

    temp.parentNode.removeChild( temp );

    if ( display === "none" ) {
        display = "block";
    }
    defaultDisplayMap[ nodeName ] = display;

    return display;
}
```

Basically, it creates a new element of the same type and inserts it into the body. It's computed `display` is considered to be the default display of the element which is being shown. This approach is so gullible, older versions of jQuery were better IMO.

Anyways, he problem is that you style `body` as a flex container. And childs of a flex container are blockified. So the computed `display` of that dummy element will be `"block"`, and that's what your element will receive, even if your element does not participate in flex layout.

So better avoid `display: flex` on the body. You can add an a wrapper instead.

```js
$('#clickme').click(function() {
  $('#test').fadeToggle();
  return false;
});
```

```css
#flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#main {
  flex: 1;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="flex">
  <div id="main">
    <span class="tools"> 
      <a class="a" href="" id="clickme">Click Me</a>
      <span id="test" class="hidden">I should be inline!</span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply flexbox to the `.tools` span

```js
     $(document).ready(function() {

       $('#clickme').click(function() {
         $('#test').fadeToggle();
         return false;
       })

     });
```

```css
#flex {
  display: flex;
  /* BREAKS JQUERY FADE, JQUERY INJECTS DISPLAY:BLOCK; */
  //flex-direction: column;

}
#main {
  flex: 1;
}
.tools {
  display: flex;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body id="flex">

  <div id="main">

    <span class="tools"> 
    <a class="a" href="#01" id="clickme">Click Me</a>
    <span id="test" class="hidden">I should be inline!</span>
    </span>

  </div>
```

Comment: Works for the example but this just wraps the entire span, it should remain inline ...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, You mean you don't want the hidden span to break *ever*? `white-space:nowrap` will do that.

Comment: Not in this case and not by default .. a span should always be an inline element .. the custom function works, kind of hackish, but it works and easy enough .. for some reason I hate adding CSS via javascript/jquery .. might just be me

Comment: Then as I said, I suspect you'll have to write your own function.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, something like this is what works:

```
$.fn.inline = function() {
    this.css({'display':'inline'});
};
```

Usage:

```
$('el').fadeToggle().inline();
```